# Спецификация для товаров

Tags: json, стандарт

Для разработки *CRM* системы надо сделать очень много интеграций с внешними маркетплейсами, *CMS* системами и т.д. Надо передавать между системами данные о товарах, категориях, брендах, остатках. У всех своя структура данных, вот и вопрос существует ли спецификация общепринятая для передачи данных между сервисами и в целом что-то такое к чему б стремились все, привести к единному стандарту? К примеру прайс-лист в одном формате чтобы все интернет магазины (поставщики) отдавали.

Нашёл на Schema https://schema.org/Product но это как бы больше для СЕО а не для API, гугл выдал мне сайт, где описана такая же проблемма как в меня https://jsoncommerce.org/ru но решения и там нет, проэкт скорее всего заброшен. Существуют ли вообще такие стандарты или все делают как умеют?

Comment: Общих стандартов нет. Существуют JSON схемы описания различных сущностей (адрес, мероприятие, человек, продукт), но они предназначены в первую очередь, как Вы и указали, для разметки данных. Используйте GraphQL, OData, REST API для создания интерфейсов между различными системами.

Comment: @XelaNimed я так и делаю по большому счету. Но хотелось бы чтоб был какой то общепринятый стандарт, ну примерно как в даты RFC3339. Наверное еще интернет до етого не созрел. Буду наверное использовать описание сущностей как на schema.org чтобы стантартизированное хоть что-то было.

Comment: Смысла использовать описание из schema.org никакого нет, т.к. это ни коим образом Вам не поможет, а проблем при необходимости добавления новых свойств или взаимосвязей добавит. Не забывайте, что у разных категорий товаров разные свойства: ISBN, мощность, срок действия лицензии, вес, цвет и т.д. Вы не сможете в одной сущности описать все возможные свойства - это невозможно. Остаток - это вообще не о товаре, а скорее о WMS. Категории - тут всё неоднозначно, т.к. одна и та-же категория может быть в нескольких других. Посмотрите как это устроено у существующих систем.